# Suppose m=5 (2^5 Bytes) , n=1 , physical address space=144 bits

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, paging

i) what is logical address space?

ii) what is page size?

iii) what is the size of a page number?

iv) what are the total number of pages in Main Memory?

v.) how many pages required to load this process in Main memory?

vi) how many total pages in Main Memory?

vii) if OS takes 5 pages, how many other pages left for user processes?

**Exactly that question with same information has been asked in exam. so I need correct answer if anyone can oblige to me on that.**

Answer (score 0):

You are about to be inundated with angry sounding messages about checking out how to post a reasonable question, etc...  These aren't avenging trolls, they are right, this isn't an idiots guide to whatever pleases you, and there is an expectation that you have put in as much work to properly frame your question as the person who answers has.

Logical address space is the range of addresses a program may reference without generating an exception.

Address space has a granularity; that granularity is colloquially known as page size.

The size of the page number is the number of bits required to express the maximum address in the logical address space divided by the page size.

I don't know what Main memory is; but the computer system you use certainly has some way to query this.

It depends upon how big *this* is; but if you have a decent system, you should be able to run the program size to find out how much memory the program requires to load.

If there are 11 pages, and the OS takes 5, then there are 6 pages left.
If there are 12 pages, and the OS takes 5, then there are 7 pages left.
...
If there are 13000 pages, and the OS takes 5, then there are 12995 pages left.

So, I answered almost all of your questions, but if you understand the mildly sarcastic tone, it is pointing you in the direction of the bits of useful information you omitted.   But, if you didn't get that, and Cut+Paste these answers onto your exam, you will likely fail.   Profs read slashdot, oh, uh, I mean stack overflow.